# nvidia 430 drivers boot hang: black screen during bootstrap

Tags: 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. It starts bootstrap, but it hangs saying nothing (blink cursor)

I tried last boot with nouveau.modeset=0.  But it still hangs, it shows a black screen with like an terminal cursor, but no keyboard response.

The bootstrap is plenty of failures, but the most relevant was: "signature not signed with a trusted key"

To solve this issue, read my answer to this post below.

To get the errors instead of the black screen, boot in recovery mode, then root console, and then you've to activate the journalctl history (I googled it).  Boot normal again to capture the errors, and then root console again and write:

journalctl -b-1

Comment: Try hitting ctrl+alt+F2 that should take you to the terminal with a login prompt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: ctr+alt+F2 doesn't work.  neither with F2 nor F1...F12

Comment: yes, it could be a duplicate of this link.  thanks! I'm afraid this topic is like the index of a encyclopedia... my case should be the third one: something else caused your problem.  I'm reading it and I'll close or continue this issue.  I'll read my log again

Answer (score 1):

It was a Nvidia 430 specific problem saying: "signature not signed with a trusted key"

First I did the next, https://askubuntu.com/a/1125176/413243 , and it made some changes but I still had

Then I did https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1061656/linux/gtx1650-notebook-not-working-on-ubuntu16-04-black-screen-amp-login-loop-/post/5376983/#5376983
And my computer is working again