# Sudden wifi connection loss

Tags: networking, wireless

I’m running Ubuntu 18.04 on a 64 bit system. I have had no issues with wifi connectivity in the past. Today, my computer suddenly lost sight of all wifi networks in my house (other devices remained connected without interruption).

I have tried ping localhost and nothing seems wrong. After some digging, I tried the command

dmesg

I can’t interpret any of the output, but in red is the message “PKCS#7 substitutes not signed with a trusted key.”

I have no clue what has gone sideways, and an open to suggestions. Please let me know if you need any more info - I’m not an experienced Linux user, so be very literal and direct if asking for more details.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you recently changed the "Secure Boot" value in your UEFI/BIOS to "Enabled"? Alternatively, does your system have an Nvidia graphics adapter?

Comment: Did you run `apt upgrade` or boot into a newer kernel? Maybe the driver needs a recompile.

Comment: I have not changed Secure Boot. I checked, and the graphics card is Intel. Thanks

Comment: I have not run apt upgrade - trying it now, everything requires internet connection to upgrade.

Comment: I wonder [if this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1125176/1222991) may address the issue 

Comment: Regrettably not... I’m beginning to think that perhaps this is a hardware issue. Any recommendations how to check if this is the case? My next step is to plug into Ethernet and see if that gets me connected (my guess is yes, but I don’t have cables handy)

Comment: Do you have another computer that you could use to download a LiveUSB onto a flash drive?  You could boot from that device and test your hardware.